# Point to grow and shrink by using gl_PointSize

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm Trying to grow and shrink an point by using this function `glPointSize()`

```
    float i;
    for (i = 0.0; i < 400.0; i ++) {
        glPointSize(i);
    }
    while (i > 0.0) {
        glPointSize(i);
        i--;
    }
```

it just point, Couldn't know how to make it move?

Answer (score 1):

Implementations have a limitation on the size of points. The `GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE` can be used to fetch this limit, but it will generally be rather less than 400. A larger point size will be clamped to this range.

Comment: ... what "does not work"? I didn't suggest that you do anything except stay within the limits of point sizes. And how does a "for loop" fix that?

Comment: I just think of that, to initialize and variable and compare it with 400. since its smaller than 400 increment the pointsize. till its equal to 400 then decrements. Still the problem there.

Comment: There is no variable. The thing you should be checking is the point size range, which you query from `glGetIntegerv` (which will return two integers). It's not a variable; it's a runtime *constant* defined by OpenGL. There's nothing to increment. It represents the largest legal point size you can use.

Comment: And unless you draw each point within the loop at a different location, or start a new frame, you're just going to see the biggest point